# Editing XML with python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am trying to edit this XML using xml.dom.minidom in python, but am not sure how to get to the values I need to change.

I access this chunk by doc.getElementsByTagName()

```
           <SVCExtension xsi:type="typens:SVCExtension">
              <Enabled>true</Enabled>
              <Info xsi:type="typens:PropertySet">
                 <PropertyArray xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty">
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>WebEnabled</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string">true</Value>
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>WebCapabilities</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string">GetCapabilities,GetMap,GetFeatureInfo,GetStyles,GetLegendGraphic,GetSchemaExtension</Value>
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                 </PropertyArray>
              </Info>
              <Props xsi:type="typens:PropertySet">
                 <PropertyArray xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty">
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>onlineResource</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string">*censored url*</Value>
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>customGetCapabilities</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string">false</Value>
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>pathToCustomGetCapabilitiesFiles</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>pathToCustomSLDFile</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>inheritLayerNames</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string">false</Value>
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>name</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string">WMS</Value>
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>title</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>abstract</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>keyword</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>contactPerson</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>contactPosition</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>contactOrganization</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>address</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>addressType</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>city</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>stateOrProvince</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>postCode</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>country</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>contactVoiceTelephone</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>contactFacsimileTelephone</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>contactElectronicMailAddress</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>fees</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                    <PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
                       <Key>accessConstraints</Key>
                       <Value xsi:type="xs:string" />
                    </PropertySetProperty>
                 </PropertyArray>
              </Props>
              <TypeName>WMSServer</TypeName>
           </SVCExtension>
```

Now, within here I would like to change "customGetCapabilities" value to "true" and specify a url in "pathToCustomGetCapabilitiesFiles".

Can someone teach me how to parse through to those values please? Thank you

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Have a look at ElementTree for XML parsing, which is easy to use, well documented and feature rich

Comment: I have looked into using ElementTree. However, it adds a lot of problems rewriting the xml. It seems to be stripping namespaces before it writes the xml back out, which I don't want to do.

Comment: If ElementTree (or particularly lxml.etree) is round-tripping inaccurately, that's surprising (*very* surprising in the latter case), and grounds for a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The following is one way you could do this with minidom.

```
props = doc.getElementsByTagName('PropertySetProperty')
for prop in props:
    if prop.hasChildNodes():
        key = prop.getElementsByTagName('Key')[0]
        if key.firstChild.nodeValue == 'customGetCapabilities':
            value = key.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("Value")[0]
            value.firstChild.nodeValue = 'true'

        if key.firstChild.nodeValue == 'pathToCustomGetCapabilitiesFiles':
            path_url = key.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('Value')[0]
            path_url.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('http://someurl/'))
            break
```